# Angular 5 HttpClient Error response not catchable

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-http, angular-http-interceptors, angular-httpclient

We're working with Angular 5 and a Spring 2 OAuth Backend.
Now when I send an old token it's of course expired. It returns status code: 401 and an error response with invalid token and so on. Now I can't see it in my logs or when I catch the error. I want to get the error so I can at first log it and later on either refresh the token or send him to the Login Page.

Now if i subscribe to the request with:

```
.subscribe(res => {
    //just random stuff.
    }, err => {
    console.log("error", err);
});
```

[I just see this response in the log with an unknown error like in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJotF.png)

Could it be failure of the backend? Because i also see in the logs something like a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present"-error, although it's because of the invalid token.

[Although I can see this response code in Google Chrome Dev Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBqK7.png)
and a 401 status code.

So I tried to find a solution myself. I've already got an interceptor and tried it with some solutions

```
return next.handle(authReq)
  .catch(error => {
    console.log("im in here");
    console.log(error);
    return Observable.throw(error);
  });
```

The Http Service just throws an error that catch is not a function without even logging the error or the "im in here".

I have also tried with the .do after next.handle and I got the same error like catch

```
.do((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
    if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
      // do stuff with response if you want
    }
  }, (err: any) => {
  console.log(err);
    if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
      if (err.status === 401) {
      }
    }
  });
```

I've tried with pipe after the http.get but it doesn't work either.

```
http.get(...).pipe(
  retry(3), // retry a failed request up to 3 times
  catchError(this.handleError) // then handle the error
);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

    Somefunc(){
    this.httpClient
          .get("data-url")
          .subscribe(
            data => console.log('success', data),
            error => console.log('oops', error)
          );
    }


    OR

this.httpClient
      .get("data-url")
      .catch((err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        // simple logging, but you can do a lot more, see below
        console.error('An error occurred:', err.error);
      });
```

Should work.

Comment: thanks for your help. but this isn't working. i've already described at the beginning that I can't get the right error log from this. 
when i do subscribe: it logs the wrong thing
and when i do with catch: i can't do subscribe afterwards

Comment: Is it the same with Http rather than HttpClient? Unable to catch errors?

Comment: yeah, it's also almost the same response. status: 0 and unknown error. although i see in dev tools: 401 and this time unauthorized

Comment: Its to do with HttpClient. Can you recheck your code again. Are you not able to capture the error even in Http?

Comment: no. so it may be a problem with spring framework and the access Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. it is set for options and if you have an authorized token it works but maybe if it's unauthorized it's also a problem so the browser doesn't provide the right error message or even angular. would you agree?

Comment: Not a backend issue if you are able to capture the error from Http. But since it works with Http and are unable to capture right error from HttpClient but get it in Http, you might have to check your HttpClient code. For me it seems like you UI code.

Comment: no, sorry i can not capture the error with normal httpmodule either (so normal http)! i just can see it in google chrome dev tools. so what do you think?

Comment: What error is your backend serving. Are you using an error handler middleware or lib for error handling ?

Comment: Like I said this 'seems' to be HttpClient issue

Comment: it was a problem with the backend. it allowed cors for options and allows authorized get but no cors for unauthorized. now it's allowed and I can get the error

Comment: That should not matter. Whether cors allowed or not errors need to be captured. Seems like a bug in code or framework

Comment: but now it works. so i'm happy but of course it's a bug. but I've also read somewhere that the browser itselfs captures and don't let it go

Comment: No HttpClient logic is supposed to capture it. Why not raise a bug ticket with angular github